# Docker: Push Image directly to Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: docker, cloud-foundry, dockerhub

I am very new to using docker, so thank you in advance for bearing with me. Essentially, I am curious if it is at all possible to create a docker image on your local PC and then push that docker image directly from your PC to Pivotal Cloud Foundry. I want to circumvent the step of pushing my local image to dockerhub first before pushing to PCF if at all possible in order to aid in more rapid development.

Answer (score 1):

You can push a docker image from your local/dev machine to any docker registry. If it is a private registry, you will need the right credentials.

You don't need to push it to DockerHub first to get it to a different registry.

We use Artifactory at work. The docker images we build are pushed directly to the private docker registry run using Artifactory.

PCF needs to be able to access the docker registry where you are storing your docker images. DockerHub happens to be one such docker registry. If you intend to use DockerHub, then you cannot avoid having to push the image to DockerHub first before your app running on PCF can access it.